# Can I remove all blood on Monster Hunter Tri?

Tags: monster-hunter-tri

I've heard that there is options to remove blood in this game, but I want to make sure this removes *all* the blood, player and monster, and not just some of it.  Is there a way to have a blood free experience?

Just to make sure there's no confusion, I'm referring to the wii exclusive monster hunter game.

Comment: I played that for over 800 hours and don't remember blood. You see specific body part damage (broken claws/horns/beaks, ripped wings), but blood?

Comment: @NelsonI I think OP is talking about red flash that happens when you hit a monster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you can't**

Monster Hunters games have a visual effect (most often red flashes) to tell you precisely when and where you hit a monster.
There are usually options to tune it down, but there's always a little effect left.

Given that it gives great information about hitting monsters or not (as they don't flinch every time you hit them), it's not hard to understand why they don't make such an option.
You should also avoid build that revolves around critical hits, as these have often bigger hit effects to differentiate them from regular hits.

I also want to add that there are never blood-related effects on players (except for Bleeding status, but wasn't here in MH Tri), so you don't have to worry about this side of your problem.

I don't personally own this specific game nor Wii, but I have experience with Monster Hunter games as a whole, plus I searched before making an answer for this game.
As a last note, you might be able to do entirely hide hit effects through some sideways solutions, like hacks, but I can't help you with that.

Comment: Ok, so if I set it to "None," it will probably be a minimal red hit indicator.  The only other thing I'm wondering about is the sea monsters.  According to ESRB they have more realistic blood, so I wonder how the settings affect them?

Comment: @Millard Probably, I don't know to which extend it'll be reduced but there'll be still something left ^^ Well, sry about that but Tri is the only game with water dive combat :/ I remember playing some hours of this game on some friends console (was Ultimate version if I remember well), remember that these combat were actually pretty cool and fun (wondering why they removed it :/) but I can't remember if these effects were differents underwater '-'

Comment: Well, thnx for the help! Sounds like a pretty cool game.  Will probably look more into the underwater stuff, I will post if I find anything.  Cheers!